# How to get the last line of output from the loop for duplicate wordcount program in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file

Almost I got the output but some touchups are needed.In this code I can get the Total repeated words count from the  text files through a folder directory.Now the problem is I want to get the output lines which I highlighted in the images(attached ones).
 For example I had 2 text files in that folder directory,
The 1st text file repeated word count is 4 and 2nd text file repeated word count is 31.
My present output shows count addition for word by word.

But I want the lastline (final count) from the output(you can see the image attachment for my present output).The highlighted lines were the final line of each text files.I want to omit the remaining lines.
So,
My output should be

```
Total words counted: 4 (text file 1)
Total words counted: 31(text file 2)
```

So that i can run 2000+text files from that folder to get all the output once.

I am a beginner to java. :)
Code is below:

```
package ramki;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class newrepeatedcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".txt");
            }
        };
        File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder\\");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
            try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader ins = null;
            try {
                ins = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(file1)));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String st = null;
            try {
                st = IOUtils.toString(ins);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // split text to array of words
            String[] words = st.split("\\s");
            // frequency array
            int[] fr = new int[words.length];
            // init frequency array
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < fr.length; i1++)
                fr[i1] = -1;
            // count words frequency
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    if (words[i1].equals(words[j])) {
                        fr[i1]++;

                    }
                }
            }

            // clean duplicates
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    if (words[i1].equals(words[j])) {
                        if (i1 != j)
                            words[i1] = "";

                    }
                }
            }
            // show the output
            int total = 0;
            // System.out.println("Duplicate words:");
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                if (words[i1] != "") {
                    System.out.println(words[i1] + "=" + fr[i1]);
                    total += fr[i1];
                }
                System.out.println("Total words counted: " + total);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my output screenshots

[image: My output]
[image: My output]

Any suggestions Welcomed.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Why don't you move last print statement out of the loop@Ram Ki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your last print statement to the out of the loop and use `File#getName()` to get file name.

```
for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
if(words[i1]!=""){
//System.out.println(words[i1]+"="+fr[i1]);//just put it in comments
total+=fr[i1];
}

 }
System.out.println("Total words counted: "+total+" ( "+file1.getName() +" )");
```

Output:

```
Total words counted: 3 ( file1.txt )
Total words counted: 3 ( file2.txt )
```

Answer (score 1):

just move out the println out of the loop and this should work. :)
Edit: deleted the line responsible for printing words and also added file name as suggested by @Satya

```
             //show the output
            int total=0;
//System.out.println("Duplicate words:");
            for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
                if(words[i1]!=""){
                    total+=fr[i1];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total words counted: "+total+" in file - "+file1.getName());
```

Comment: YEAH i tried it. But the output also shows each word from the file.